# Google Apps Script - inline images example doesn't work

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to get this example script working from [this Google Developer page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#methods).

I put the below code, which is copy/pasted verbatim (except for the "recipient@example.com" of course) into a function which runs when a form is submitted.

```
// This code fetches the Google and YouTube logos, inlines them in an email
// and sends the email
function inlineImage() {
 var googleLogoUrl = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png";
 var youtubeLogoUrl = "https://developers.google.com/youtube/images/YouTube_logo_standard_white.png";
 var googleLogoBlob = UrlFetchApp
                      .fetch(googleLogoUrl)
                      .getBlob()
                      .setName("googleLogoBlob");
 var youtubeLogoBlob = UrlFetchApp
                       .fetch(youtubeLogoUrl)
                       .getBlob()
                       .setName("youtubeLogoBlob");
 MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: "recipient@example.com",
  subject: "Logos",
  htmlBody: "inline Google Logo<img src='cid:googleLogo'> images! <br>" +
            "inline YouTube Logo <img src='cid:youtubeLogo'>",
  inlineImages:
    {
      googleLogo: googleLogoBlob,
      youtubeLogo: youtubeLogoBlob
    }
  });
}
```

The email is not sent at all and the code doesn't appear to execute.

When I remove the first 4 statements (setting up the URLs and blobs), and the inlineImages section of the sendEmail function, the email is sent.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no problem with your code.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, so I had inserted the previous-mentioned code into the function `function formSubmitReply(e) { }`. I removed it from within there, then when I ran it manually from script editor, it re-requested to authenticate to my google account. Any idea why? Or how I can get it to re-authenticate again in the future if required?

Comment: I have never asked re-authenticate again except I wanted to do something new that is required a new permission.